# How can I show multi-lingual front end system messages?

Tags: multilingual, system, messages

I have a MSM set up with site A in english and site B in chinese. What I'd like is for the system messages on site B to show in chinese rather than english (think "Thanks - you're now logged in" etc, etc).

Does anyone know if that's possible and if so how?

Cheers in advance,

Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use [this method](http://eeinsider.com/articles/multi-language-solutions-for-expressionengine/) then I have the perfect solution. the missing piece I was looking for so long!

In fact you have to find a way on how to trigger a) language related messages from add-ons, and b) language related messages AND emails from expressionengine itself.

you can do that by adding two variables within the index.php file, just before "END OF USER CONFIGURABLE SETTINGS":

a)

```
// $assign_to_config['language'] = 'deutsch';
```

(attention, when activating this, you have to translate all of your add-ons, or at least, duplicate the language folders. )

b)

```
// overrides the default language for expressionengine (use the name of the language folder)
$assign_to_config['deft_lang'] = 'deutsch';
```

this is much more important and will set the language of system messages and emails!

(for multilanguage emails you have to go to: "design -> message pages -> email notifications" and de-check the checkbox for each template: "*Enable This Template? If disabled, this template will not be used. Instead, the message will be generated dynamically in each user's chosen language*"

good luck! 
stefan

Answer (score 8):

Check out the Custom System Messages addon: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/custom-system-messages

This lets you move EE system messages into EE templates so you can have finite control over messages.

Comment: As far as I can see, this won't change the {content} of the messages - only the stuff surrounding them, right?

Comment: You can deliver custom error messages based on error action: http://pastie.org/1355088

Answer (score 3):

We always use this Multi Language Module for things like these:
http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/multi-language-module

This allows you to create "phrases" in your backend and provide different translations.

You can ouput these in your template like this:

```
{exp:multi_language:phrase index=“phrase_name”}
```

Depending on the user's language this will output the correct translation.
The user’s language is determined by the url. So for a webpage at mysite.com/links/ the italian version will be at mysite.com/it/links/. This makes for easy navigation and setup in ExpressionEngine.

Comment: Does this work in EEs speciality templates though? I don't think tags are supported in those templates.

Comment: I f you want to redirect users to a specific page to let them know they're logged out, I wouldn't use EE's templates. With FreeMember you can redirect users to any page you want, where you can use the multi-language module.  http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/freemember

Comment: That looks GREAT Janvi. Thanks for the heads up on that one.

Comment: if that answers your question, could you mark it as such  ? :)

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question I'm afraid. I'm specifically talking about the language that EEs messages are displayed in (think what's in {content} in the speciality templates).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need an add-on for this, you can set the default language per MSM site.

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Media Girl on this one. I use Custom System Messages to display all error pages and i've never looked at another solution. It's simple and effective.